# Any other way to clip container except for CSS clip-path?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I've been trying to find a solution for the 3d day and I am going crazy now. I need to clip a container to a specific shape. The container has a background image with `background-attachment: fixed;` so it's not static (from the viewers point of view). The layer behind the shaped container is not static also, so I cannot just use some png mask to overlay my container. CSS `clip-path` works perfectly for all major browsers except for IE! Support for IE 10 and 11 is a must according to my client, so I am trying to find a solution for this. Is there anything I can use to replace clip-path with? Thanks in advance!

I've found this article (https://css-tricks.com/background-image-shapes/) that perfectly describes my issue, except that the image I am working with has `background-attachment: fixed;`

Comment: How about an extra element in front of the background using a data-url svg instead? Examples here - https://sarasoueidan.com/blog/css-svg-clipping/

Comment: @Rycochet It's already implemented to ensure FF support. However, it's not supported by IE too ;-(

Comment: the hardcore-solution: compute the offset of the container and draw the clipped image to a canvas?

Comment: what kind of shape are we talking about?

Comment: @Thomas It's something like this that I want to achieve: https://jsfiddle.net/5jhrp4za/1/. The green part is a Google Map.

Comment: @Thomas, I could rotate it with transform (and rotate back its content), but it's got to be paralel with other layers, so the angle computation gets too ugly (as the code itself).

Comment: Does it have to be a pure css solution?

Comment: @Iharby Taken the time I've spent, NOT AT ALL! )

Comment: I don't have much to go on, but I was thinking as jQuery is cross browser compatible it might offer some solution to solve this issue. I found this: http://jqueryrotate.com/ although I am not sure how helpful it is _It uses CSS3 where applicable and falls back to a CANVAS (old firefox, some less known browsers) or VML (IE6) solution where possible_

Comment: There is a fiddle linked from that page with wrapper examples. http://jsfiddle.net/xcnas330/ I just changed `var rt = $(this).data('rotation') + 90` to `var rt = $(this).data('rotation') + 45` as an experiment.

Comment: @lharby, well I could rotate it with transform: rotate(5deg) or something like that. The code gets really dirty in this case with an angle computation.

Comment: if it is just a simple geometrical shape, you can acieve this by transforming divs into shape and giving them a collective Background-image. should work in any browser that supports css-transforms (http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d). I don't have the time to implement an example now, maybe i'll do this later, in a few hours.